# presenting view from popover

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

In my app a user can press a tableviewcell which shows a popover with a button in it's header. Pressing this button will present a navigation view controller.

```
DNWInfoViewController *infoViewController = [[DNWInfoViewController alloc] initWithInfoText:infoText];
    UINavigationController *navController    = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:infoViewController];
    navController.modalPresentationStyle     = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But since iOS 8 I get this warning and the view doesn't show up:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x180e1dc0>  on <ANProjectFilterViewController: 0x16ec5cf0> which is already presenting (null)
```

This must be because the popovercontroller is still showing so I tried this before presenting the view

```
[_ppvrController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; // This will not call the delegate
```

This 'fix' works some times. But most of the times it still shows the warning and not my view. I tried manually calling the delegate but that gave the same results.

This used to work great in iOS 7 and lower. How can I present a new view from a popover in iOS 8?

**EDIT 1**

Show I've found that

```
dismissPopoverAnimated
```

doesn't work in iOS 8 for some reason. Normally when a user selects an item from the popover a method is called which first dismisses the popover and then does some custom stuff. In iOS 7 the popover disappears on selection but not in iOS 8.

**EDIT 2**

So what actually triggers the warning is this piece of code:

```
[_ppvrController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

This piece of code is inside a method. That method is called from a button which is inside the presented popover. Half of the time the popup is succesfully dismissed but sometimes it just prints the warning en the popover stays visible.

Note: there's no other code inside this method. Just that one line to dismiss the popover.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That seems a bug on iOS 8. I suggest you [report it](http://bugreport.apple.com) to Apple. In the meantime, I read that other people are using this workaround:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self presentViewController:yourNewNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the same warning. Did Apple say something about this in the release notes? I don't understand why this is working fine in older iOS versions.

Comment: I've found that dismissPopoverAnimated doesn't work correctly in iOS 8

Comment: Seems like the same behavior. Sometimes it works, sometimes it shows the warning. Ill report the bug and accept the answer since theres no fix for this.

Comment: How about if you try calling it after an arbitrary delay? `double delayInSeconds = 0.01;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self presentViewController:yourNewNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
});`

Comment: Nope sorry still not working. After the delay the warning just pops up. Please check my edit in my question where I added another thing I found.

Comment: i wonder how they are doing it in their own SDK e.g. `UIActivityController` presents many other controllers

Answer (score 1):

Just move the presentViewController in an own method and call this with performSelectorOnMainthread

That should work

Comment: I tried ricardo's answer which shows the same behavior. This looks like a bug in iOS 8.